# Add transition after the hovering effect in CSS

Tags: css

How will I add a transition to this CSS code after the hovering effect. The image is a background image of div. What I wanted is to add a transition between the zoom effect.

```
.animations {
background: url('resources/image.jpg');
background-size: 300px 300px;
height: 250px;
transition: 10s ease-out;
}

.animations:hover {
animation: effect 2s forwards;

}

@keyframes effect {
0%{background-size: 100%}
100%{background-size: 120%;}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In .animation and .animation:hover you put something like this:

```
transition:2s linear;
-webkit-transition:2s linear;
-mos-transition:2s linear;
```

And in the .animation:hover you put the change you want to make, like:

```
.animations {
background-color: #000;
transition:0.4s linear;
-webkit-transition:0.4s linear;
-mos-transition:0.4s linear;
}

.animations:hover {
background-color: #fff;
transition:0.4s linear;
-webkit-transition:0.4s linear;
-mos-transition:0.4s linear;
}
```

In this example it will transition from black to white in 0.4s (change linear to whatever you want)

Comment: The animation that I've given is for panning the background image in <div> and panning it again once I remove the mouse pointer from the image.

Comment: You can add any commands inside .animations and .animations:hover, and it will transition to what you have set to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .animations {
            background-image: url('https://data.whicdn.com/images/273956252/superthumb.jpg?t=1484219209');
            background-size: 50% 50%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            height: 100%;
            transition: 10s ease-in;
            -webkit-transition:10s ease-in;
            -moz-transition:10s ease-in;
            }   

            .animations:hover {
            animation: effect 2s forwards;
            }   
            @keyframes effect {
            0%{background-size: 50% 50%;}
            100%{background-size: 100% 100%;}
            
            }
        </style>
        <title>css</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="animations">Images</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope above information will be useful for you.

Thank you.